# How to set the stream as ImageSource in Xamarin UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagesource, xamarin.uwp

I am having the stream and I trying to set the Image Source as a stream. My code is

```
var contentPage = new ContentPage();
var image = new Image();
Stream stream = args.Stream;
stream.Position = 0;
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
contentPage.Content = image;
Navigation.PushModalAsync(contentPage);
```

Image rendered in android and iOS but it not worked in UWP. Please suggest me, how to render the image via stream.

Thanks,
Santhiya A

Comment: Try to use memorystream.  ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this also in UWP and have found that you should do this work in the OnAppearing() method of the contentPage.